# net use, save user + password over new ssh connections

Tags: ssh, window, net-use

When I'm connecting to a qemu windows VM via SSH(Don't know if it makes a difference for my question), every time I use 'net use'(`net use Z: \\x\y`), I need to enter username + password.

How can I save the info so that a new ssh connection could use the net drive without verification?

Comment: You can try to use /SAVECRED option. It should ask for username/password the first time then save credential so you don't have to input it the next time : `net use Z: \\x\y /SAVECRED`

Comment: After using /SAVECRED, when connecting with a new ssh connection I'm still required to enter username + password

Comment: Another option is to use /PERSISTANT option to make net drive persistant : `net use Z: \\x\y /PERSISTANT:yes`

Comment: Should I run these in an SSH connection or from my local cmd?

Comment: You must run this command on the system on which you want to create and keep the net drive.